# libusb-1.0.so.0 error

Tags: 16.04, 32-bit

I'm tyring to run service haspd.service but get an error:

```
ноя 22 17:50:55 ubuntu-server haspd[5918]: Running winehasp... [PASSED]
ноя 22 17:50:55 ubuntu-server haspd[5918]: Running hasplm... [PASSED]
ноя 22 17:50:55 ubuntu-server haspd[5918]: Running hasplmd... [PASSED]
ноя 22 17:50:55 ubuntu-server haspd[5918]: usbkeytest: error while loading shared libraries: libusb-1.0.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
ноя 22 17:50:55 ubuntu-server haspd[5918]: We have no built usbkeytest, so run all possible services
ноя 22 17:50:55 ubuntu-server haspd[5918]: Running skeyd... [PASSED]
ноя 22 17:50:55 ubuntu-server systemd[1]: haspd.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=2
ноя 22 17:50:55 ubuntu-server systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Hasp keys support.
```

found in the internet, that i should install libudev0:i386, but i have ubuntu 16.04 and this package was removed in 14.04 and i can't do it
I'm newbie in linux, help me please...

Comment: What is this "haspd" service?

Comment: counldn't add a haspd tag because it required 300 askubuntu rate.
thats the package for hardware license management (http://download.etersoft.ru/pub/Etersoft/HASP/last/Ubuntu/16.04/haspd_7.40-eter9ubuntu_i386.deb)

Comment: Tags are not the problem, the problem is that we have no idea what this "haspd" thing is, or how you installed it. (Besides, the "haspd" tag does not exist.)

Comment: haspd is a RSA key hardware license manager. in ubuntu 14.04 it's installation did not require any additional dependencies or packages. In 16.04 x64 it does, so i made
dpkg --add-architecture i386
apt-get update
apt-get install ia32-libs
i understand, that it's not clear for those who didn't use it, but i hope someone could...

Answer (score 3):

`libusb-1.0.so.0` is actually from the package [`libusb-1.0-0`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/libusb-1.0-0) which is available in Xenial.

To install for the native `amd64` architecture:

```
sudo apt install libusb-1.0-0
```

I don't see why you'd need it for a different architecture in this situation. If, for some reason, you do need the `i386` variant you can install it like this:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt update
sudo apt install libusb-1.0.0:i386
```

Answer (score 1):

This instructions above didn't worked for me, what worked for me was simply deleting everything from /opt/resolve, so if you find yourself in this situation, just do a:

```
rm -rf /opt/resolve
```

Answer (score 0):

Just run:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386 && apt-get update
sudo apt install libusb-1.0.0:i386
```

Comment: Can you explain what these commands are trying to do?